# How to work with variables in Cloudformation template as the feature of "Data source" in terraform

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In terraform, we can use [data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) to get the exist resource details.

But in cloudformation, **if the resource isn't created by cloudformation template**, I can't find any ways to reference it, unless I hard code the value, such as real vpc id.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tagged Terraform here because you're using Terraform to run CloudFormation or just as a comparison?

Comment: I add tag `terraform` is only for the topic related.

Comment: I currently run `aws ec2 describe-vpcs ...` to get the detail of vpc and feed as environment variables.

Comment: I found a work around. with Terraform, it can deploy cloudformation template as well, So I can use terraform data source to get the exist resource detail and feed to terraform cloudfomation resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made a vpc stack with cloudformation, it gets parameter input from aws cli and output the vpc id, subnet id, etc.

This cloudformation template has only one null resource (because cloudformation will report error if no resource in its template).

```
Description: >
  This template deploys a VPC, with a pair of public and private subnets spread
  across two Availabilty Zones. It deploys an Internet Gateway, with a default
  route on the public subnets. It deploys a pair of NAT Gateways (one in each AZ),
  and default routes for them in the private subnets.
Parameters:

  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that will be prefixed to resource names
    Type: String

  VPC:
    Description: Please enter the VPC ID
    Type: String

  VpcCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String

  PublicSubnet1:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String

  PublicSubnet2:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String

Conditions:
  HasNot: !Equals [ 'true', 'false' ]

Resources:
  NullResource:
    Type: 'Custom::NullResource'
    Condition: HasNot

Outputs:

  VPC:
    Description: A reference to the created VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}:VPC"

  PublicSubnet1:
    Description: A reference to the public subnet in the 1st Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}:PublicSubnet1"

  PublicSubnet2:
    Description: A reference to the public subnet in the 2nd Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}:PublicSubnet2"

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: A reference to the private subnet in the 1st Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}:PrivateSubnet1"

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Description: A reference to the private subnet in the 2nd Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}:PrivateSubnet2"

  VpcCIDR:
    Description: VPC CIDR
    Value: !Ref VpcCIDR
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}:VpcCIDR"
```

I run a bash script to collect these data (you can write javascript, pytyon or any other languages to collect these data), feed them to above cloudformation as parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )"

# collect the vpc details.
# you can run aws cli or any aws sdk to collect them.
source ../common_function.sh
echo ${VPC_ID}

aws --profile "${AWS_PROFILE}" --region "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}" \
    cloudformation deploy \
    --stack-name "${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-vpc" \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM \
    --template-file "${DIR}/vpc.yaml" \
    --parameter-overrides \
    EnvironmentName="${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}" \
    VPC="${VPC_ID}" \
    VpcCIDR="${VPC_CIDR}" \
    PublicSubnet1="${PUBLIC_SUBNET_ID_1}" \
    PublicSubnet2="${PUBLIC_SUBNET_ID_2}" \
    PrivateSubnet1="${PRIVATE_SUBNET_ID_1}" \
    PrivateSubnet2="${PRIVATE_SUBNET_ID_2}"
```

After you deploy above cfn stack, you can reference these output variables in other cfn stacks.

```
VpcId:
    'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub "${EnvironmentName}:VPC"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is use Parameter (e.g. AWS::EC2::VPC::Id for vpc ID). While creating a stack, this will list out all the existing vpcs in the region you're creating the stack in. Currently such parameters are limited to few such as volume, subnet, sg but more may come in future. Though currently there's not any exact equivalent of datasource of terraform in cloudformation as of now. You could also fashion something using cloudformation macros but that would be a bit convulted.